# Edit json in js/node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working on an nodejs app which reads data from a json file. Now I want to edit this json file in js (write to it). How do I do this ?

Here is my js code: `

```
var fs = require("fs")

//function for file input
function getFile(filename) {
  var data = fs.readFileSync(filename,"ascii")
  return data }

//parsing json
var jsonString = [getFile("File.json")]
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString)`
```

Comment: A JSON object when parsed is then like any other JS object. Use [object dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access any data you want.

Comment: for addition: jsonObj.key=value,   for deletion: delete jsonObj.key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the jsonObj as you want, create a new object or whatever, then write the file:

```
fs.writeFileSync("File.json", jsonData);
```

This will overwrite the file if it exists, so that way you edit the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can load a json file by requiring it.

```
var contents = require('/path/to/file.json');
```

Iterate `contents` just like a regular object.

Answer (score 1):

A JSON object, when parsed is, like any other JS object. Use [object dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access any data you want.

For example a value:

```
console.log(isonObi.something.value)
```

For example a value in an array:

```
console.log(isonObi.something[0].value)
```

---

> From [eyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/730754/eyp)
>
> Modify the jsonObj as you want, create a new object or whatever, then write the file:
>
> `fs.writeFileSync("File.json", jsonData);`
>   This will overwrite the file if it exists, so that way you edit the file.

Answer (score 1):

With nodeJS, you can [**require**](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) a **JSON** file.

Supposing you get this JSON file :

```
//test.json

[
  {
    "name": "toto",
    "code": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "code": "5"
  }
];
```

Then, you can require this file and perform some modification :

```
var json = require('./test.json');

json.forEach(function(elm){
    elm.name = 'test';
});
```