# How to update json entry in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How can I update json value with node.js? I found in internet couple examples but my is a little bit more complicated

I can open value I want to change

```
var contents = fs.readFileSync("./../../skill.json");
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
console.log("Address", jsonContent['manifest']['apis']['custom']['endpoint']['uri']);
```

but how to edit it with my value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit json in js/node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959696/edit-json-in-js-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var contents = fs.readFileSync("./../../skill.json");
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
console.log("Address", jsonContent['manifest']['apis']['custom']['endpoint']['uri']);
// modify your value
jsonContent['manifest']['apis']['custom']['endpoint']['uri'] = 'new value';
// stringify it and write to file
fs.writeFileSync("./../../skill.json", JSON.stringify(jsonContent));
```

Answer (score 1):

- Assignment in JavaScript is done via the [assignment operator (`=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment).
- Accessing values of an object can be done via the [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) (`.` and `[]`).

Hence, modifying the content is as straightforward as

```
jsonContent['manifest']['apis']['custom']['endpoint']['uri'] = 'value';
```

Or even:

```
jsonContent.manifest.apis.custom.endpoint.uri = 'value';
```

---

That being said, I would suggest to at least wrap the assignment in a `try catch` block so that you are not exposed to a crash if the object does not deeply match the structure you expect to receive.

A more robust and versatile solution would be to leverage [`Lodash.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/latest#set). For example:

```
_.set(jsonContent, ['manifest', 'apis', 'custom', 'endpoint', 'uri'], 'value');
```

---

As noted by @Patrick Roberts, modern JavaScript will allow leveraging the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining). This is currently only available in [stage 1](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#stage-1).

```
jsonContent?.manifest?.apis?.custom?.endpoint?.uri = 'value';
```

Comment: With a current Stage 1 proposal, you can safely update a nested property like `_.set()` does leveraging optional chaining operator: `jsonContent?.manifest?.apis?.custom?.endpoint?.uri = 'value';`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That is a valid point  Updated the response

Answer (score 0):

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);


(async (){

    try {
      var contents = await readFile("./../../skill.json");
      var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
      console.log("Address", jsonContent.manifest.apis.custom.endpoint.uri);

      // modify your value
      jsonContent.manifest.apis.custom.endpoint.uri = 'new value';

       // stringify it and write to file
       await writeFile("./../../skill.json", JSON.stringify(jsonContent));

    } catch (e){
       console.error(e);
    }

})();
```